# Applying Fold function in F#

Tags: list, f#, fold

```
 let list_min_fold = List.fold (fun acc -> List.min acc ) 0 lst
    printfn"Using regular List.fold function:\n      The minimum is: %A\n" 
       (list_min_fold)
```

When I execute my code this error displays: 
error FS0001: The type '('a -> 'b)' does not support the 'comparison' constraint. For example, it does not support the 'System.IComparable' interface

Why? Please help :(

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to find the smallest number in a list? If so, you need to use the `min` function (which takes just two arguments) rather than `List.min` (which takes a list of arguments):

To keep the code the most similar to your example, you can write (note also that starting with `0` is not going to work, so I used `System.Int32.MaxValue` instead):

```
let lst = [4;3;1;2;5;]
let list_min_fold = List.fold (fun acc -> min acc) System.Int32.MaxValue lst
```

It is also worth noting that the function you pass to fold takes two arguments - the state `acc` and the current value:

```
let list_min_fold = List.fold (fun acc v -> min acc v) System.Int32.MaxValue lst
```

But thanks to partial function application you can omit one of them (as you did), or both of them:

```
let list_min_fold = List.fold min System.Int32.MaxValue lst
```

Comment: I suggest `let listMinFold = List.fold min (List.head lst) lst`.  Returning `System.Int32.MaxValue` when `lst = []` is probably not good.

Comment: @TheInnerLight in which case you can just use `List.reduce` ;)

Comment: @Carsten absolutely true but the question was about `fold`.  That is probably also worth mentioning in the answer though.

Answer (score 2):

as always Tomas answer is spot on so I have but a small remark:

as you probably saw it makes no sense to try to find the minimum of an empty list (so the function probably should be of type `'a option` and when you have an non-empty list it's very easy to use `List.reduce` (which is basically just a `fold` for binary operations and `min` is a great candidate for such an operation):

```
let list_min xs = 
   match xs with 
   | [] -> None 
   | _  -> List.reduce min xs
           |> Some
```

this way you get:

```
> list_min [2;1;5;3];;
val it : int option = Some 1
> list_min [2;1;5;3;0];;
val it : int option = Some 0
> list_min ([] : int list);;
val it : int option = None
```

---

ok it's a fair point that the question was about *fold* - so if it has to be exactly `List.fold` you can of course do (as TheInnerLight remarked):

```
let list_min xs = 
   match xs with 
   | []      -> None 
   | (x::xs) -> List.fold min x xs
                |> Some
```

Comment: I do like the suggestion of using `Some`/`None` for the minimum to handle empty lists, especially if you're expecting to get them.  A `List.tryMin` might be handy in the standard library on occasion.